# oracle - cast timestamp with timezone to date adds 10mins for very very old dates

Tags: oracle, timestamp-with-timezone

our application generates unix epoch at America/Chicago timezone for date fields to process which is converted to date while inserting data to Oracle. While processing very very older dates like 1880, cast to date adds 10mins.

```
Unix epoch for 1880-JAN-01 = -2840119200000

select 
FROM_TZ(cast(to_date('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + (-2840119200000/86400000) AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' 
from dual;

-- 01-JAN-80 12.00.00.000000000 AM AMERICA/CHICAGO

select 
to_char(cast(FROM_TZ(cast(to_date('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + (-2840119200000/86400000) AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' as date),
'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
from dual;
-- 1880-01-01 00:10:00 (Adds 10mins)
```

Even converting timestamp with timezone to char adds 10mins -

```
select 
to_char(FROM_TZ(cast(to_date('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + (-2840119200000/86400000) AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago')
from dual;
-- 01-JAN-80 12.10.00.000000 AM AMERICA/CHICAGO
```

Then I tried creating timestamp with timezone directly which reduces 10mins -

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('1880-01-01 12.00.00.000000000 AM AMERICA/CHICAGO','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF AM TZR') FROM DUAL;
-- 31-DEC-79 11.50.00.000000000 PM AMERICA/CHICAGO
```

I tried all possible conversions but didn't get any clue for this time difference for very very old dates

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "America/Chicago" time zone for 1880 - since standard time zones in the United States were introduced only in November 1883. Perhaps the 10 minute difference you are seeing is for whatever "standard" (not based on time zones!) was used in Chicago in 1880. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_time_in_the_United_States

Comment: @mathguy Sorry for the confusion. our application generates unix epoch (long data type) in America/Chicago timezone, so at Oracle we convert long value to timestamp, convert to Americal/Chicago timezone and cast to date date type. While converting to timestamp with timezone format, there is no difference of time. However while casting to date, it adds 10mins. I still think its a bug in oracle to convert timestamp with timezone to varchar or date for dates less than 1883.

Comment: No doubt, and I believe there are other bugs in Oracle's handling of dates and timestamps, but my point was - why does this matter to whatever you are doing with that data? An "America/Chicago" timezone of any kind applied for dates in 1880 is meaningless anyway (even if there was no Oracle bug).

Comment: I agree with you. We are comparing data between two systems where we found some discrepancies for these dates. I am checking for fix or oracle bug ticket even though it may not effect any downstream.